# how to decode android xml or reverse Engineering of XML

Tags: android, xml, decompiling

here problem
i loss my android projects.i just have some APK in my mobile. i have got java files but i could not get XML files. when i extract APK than i get all resource and layouts files but my layouts files are encrypted my be UTF-8. Tell me how to  decode android XML files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</GridView>
```

Comment: this is encoded xml..    Ì                               :   R   Z   ˆ   º   Ö   ô        *  @  f  Ž     ø  ü    2  ˜  ¨  ¼  ê  ú  2  B  P  d   l a y o u t _ w i d t h   
 l a y o u t _ h e i g h t   
 b a c k g r o u n d    i d    l a y o u t _ a l i g n P a r e n t T o p    l a y o u t _ c e n t e r H o r i z o n t a l    l a y o u t _ b e l o w   
 l a y o u t _ m a r g i n    t e x t

Answer (score 1):

Solution is **[AndroidGuard](https://github.com/androguard/androguard)**.

Get your APK, extract its content.

You'll get the XMLs, but unreadable.

Then use `androaxml.py` to decode them into the original XMLs (some styles and references could be lost *but hey that's better than nothing I guess*).

Use the unreadable XML as input.

Comment: AndroidGuard is downloaded and extraced but how to use androaxml.py?

Comment: is there any commond line to use androaxml.py?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way I found is to decompile .apk file with a tool named APKIDE.Install it, and operate as follow,

1 choose Tools -->UI language -->English

[image]

2 click Project --> Open Apk --->choose .apk file

[image]